# How can I create RedHat VM and Ubuntu VM with one Vagrantfile?

Tags: ansible

Below is my Vagrantfile. However, instead of creating 1 RedHat VM and 2 Ubuntu VMs, it "vagrant up" 3 Ubuntu VMs.

Could someone let me know why?
Thank you in advance!

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 4000
    v.linked_clone = false
  end

# App server 1   
config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  config.vm.define "app1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app1.test"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.4"
  end

# App server 2   
config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/ubuntu2004"
  config.vm.define "app2" do |app|
   app.vm.hostname = "orc-app2.test"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.5"
  end

# DB server   
config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/ubuntu2004"
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "orc-db.test"
    db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.6"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are configuring the box in the wrong place and overwriting several times the default box used for any instance. The following should fix your issue and meet your requirement:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  
  # These are the defaults applied to all VMs unless overridden
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/ubuntu2004"  # Set as a default box since reused.
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 4000
    v.linked_clone = false
  end

  # Specific config for App server 1
  config.vm.define "app1" do |app|
    # Override box for this specific vm
    app.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app1.test"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.4"
  end

  # Specific config for App server 2   
  config.vm.define "app2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app2.test"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.5"
  end

  # Specific config for DB server 
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "orc-db.test"
    db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.6"
  end

end
```

*Side note*: since you have at least two VMs based on the same image, you would probably benefit from using `v.linked_clone = true`. This would most probably speed-up first creation of your vms and subsequent destroy/re-create.

Comment: thank you =) I couldn’t figure this out myself and ended up creating the centOS vm by creating another Vagrantfile separately in an another directory. Your solution really helped.